# "Best return on your money" vs "Best return for your money"

Tags: prepositions, difference, phrasal-verbs

I am confused which preposition is correct in the statement:

> Best return **on** your money.

or

> Best return **for** your money.

***?***

Which do you think is correct? Please explain.

Comment: More context please

Answer (score 1):

> Best return **on** your money.

This one is totally correct.

"Return on" is a phrasal verb which means according to [Longman Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/return):

> The amount of profit that you get from something.

That *something* would be determined if the preposition "from" was added before/after the prepositional phrase (i.e., "on" and its predicate).

Your sentence, as a whole, means *I wish you the best net profit that would be generated/resulted on your money.*

> Best return **for** your money.

This one is a bit odd. It means *I wish your money the best net profit* **instead of, for example,** *I wish you the best net profit*.

You can rewrite it:

> Best return *for you*.

to be realistic and correct. And, it would mean *I wish you the best net profit.*

Note: The profit may be a gain or loss, but regardless both cases, your sentence first part indicates that I'm wishing you **the best**.